# Reduce an array of dictionary with many keys to an array of dictionary with a single key in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of an questions that can be selected

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "test",
    "info": "Test123",
    "is_selected": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "test2",
    "info": "test2",
    "is_selected": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "test23",
    "info": "test23",
    "is_selected": true
  }
]
```

How do we reduce this array of dictionary with many keys to an array of dictionary with a single key

```
[
  {
    "question_id": 1
  },
  {
    "question_id": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map your array with something like this:

```
let secondArray: [[String : Int]] = array.compactMap { dict in
    guard let id = dict["id"] as? Int else { return nil }
    return ["question_id" : id]
}
```

but what's the point of returning dicts with a single key and not just an array of values...(?)

```
let questionIds = array.compactMap { dict in
    return dict["id"]
}
```

Comment: The api wants [["question_id": 4], ["question_id": 5], ["question_id": 8]] for the selected  questions as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`, then inside its closure get the value corresponding to the key `id` and store it in a new dictionary under the key `question_id`.

```
let dictionariesWithSingleKey = dictionariesWithManyKeys.reduce(into: [[String:Int]](), { result, current in
    guard let questionId = current["id"] as? Int else { return }
    let singleKeyedDict = ["question_id": questionId]
    result.append(singleKeyedDict)
})
print(dictionariesWithSingleKey)
```

Comment: Okay, but in Swift 5 it throws: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'result' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: @vedrano this piece of code still compiles perfectly fine for me using Swift 5.5. Are you sure you used the correct `reduce`? There are several overloaded versions of `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Const: String {
    case id = "id"
    case questionId = "question_id"
}

let reduced = dict.reduce([]) {
    guard let element = $1[Const.id.rawValue] else {
        return $0
    }
    return $0 + [[Const.questionId.rawValue: element]]
}
```

Or you can just reduce it to an array of ints (just for store ids without any "key" because they're the same in every dictionary)